# Image upload with queued event

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was doing some research regarding image uploading with queued events, and I come across this topic saying I cannot use queue to upload image.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581810/implementing-queue-for-image-processing-in-laravel-what-to-queue-and-what-not)

What I want to do is to use Intervention to modify image(resize and change extension) and upload it to S3 with queued events.

If the topic is true what would be the best way to handle this without keeping users waiting for the event to be finished background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may have misunderstood the answer on that question.

While you **can't** queue the `User Browser -> Laravel App` upload, you absolutely **can** queue the `Laravel App -> Amazon S3` upload, as well as the image processing you wish to do with Intervention.

All you have to do is create a [queued job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) that performs both the [upload to S3](https://chrisblackwell.me/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-laravel/) and transformation, and in your controller handling the user upload request, you create and push that job to the queue.

With that said, if you want to optimize performance by letting the user upload files to your Laravel app in an asynchronous fashion while they work on something else, you might want to take a look into [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) and [asynchronously uploading files with HTML5](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So, All I have to do is move the image somewhere (e.g public folder) from a temporary path and upload it to S3 from there?

Comment: Yep! If you don't plan on serving the raw image directly from your Laravel app (perhaps due to server load issues), you can use the `storage` folder instead. You can also remove the raw image on the queued job after you're finished (a lot of people forget that), so your disk doesn't get filled with old data.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t pass an uploaded file instance to a job. You need to write it to disk somewhere, and then retrieve it when handling the job.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).